# Calling a method outside class statically, passing other method's output as parameter

Tags: php, class, methods, parameters

I have a class like this:

```
class myClass {

    public static function load() 
    {
        return new self();
    }

    public function myMethod1 ()
    {
        return 'content';
    }

    public function myMethod2 ($content)
    {
        return 'modified '.$content;
    }

}
```

Somewhere in my script, I have to call `myMethod2` using `myMethod1`'s output as parameter.

The way I currently do that, is:

```
echo myClass::load()->myMethod2(myClass::load()->myMethod1()); // modified content
```

It works, but I'm pretty confident there is a more appropriate way... So my questions:

- Is there a proper way of passing method's output as other method's parameter in a class loaded "statically"?
- Besides that, there is a more elegant code structure to accomplish the same "task"?

Thanks! 
(This is my first question in StackOverflow, I apologize for mistakes, eventually)

Comment: Hello! You could consider posting this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Thanks for the suggestion, it seems a more appropriate place!

Comment: i don't think here you are passing method as parameter. Actually what happens is that first the inner method is called and output of the call is passed as parameter for outer call. I think you should look for callback functions here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: @g-newa You're right, I changed the question title accordingly